# 1955 Chrysler Windsor no response when I turn the key

Tags: battery, starting, wiring, chrysler, classic

I have had this car for a while and have had it running for a while but suddenly it stopped working. When I turn the key there is absolutely no response; no lights no clicks, no starter activity. The battery is charged and the connections are clean. I hooked up the terminals from the car to another car to "jumpstart" it, but there was no response from the Windsor at all. I'm still going through the wiring but I'M a bit perplexed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Wondering if the ignition switch is the issue, but I couldn't tell you how to diagnose it.

Comment: Was this converted to 12 volt? If so, is there a fuse in the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

As you say the warning lights don't come on, I would suggest that you have managed to knock a wire off somewhere.

This would either be at the battery or more probably on the starter solenoid / relay. Older cars did not tend to feed directly off the battery terminal - the electrical feed was from the solenoid so that should be checked.

The wire may still be attached but it could be broken from bending so it needs to be checked.

What you could try is to follow the wire from the solenoid to the fuse box and run a feed direct from the battery to provide power bypassing that lead. If things start to work then you have found the issue. It will be a VERY good idea to have a fuse in that lead close to the battery - a headlight bulb in series works well as it allows about 5A to flow and you can't melt anything.